# How to connect to MySQL server on another host?

Tags: mysql, django, database-connection

Django can simply connect to its own MySQL server by setting `HOST` and `PORT` in `settings.py` as '' (empty string):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'dbname',                   # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'root',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'root',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

My question is how to make it able to connect another database on another host? Suppose my machine is `192.168.1.33` and another machine to be connected is `192.168.1.34`, both are on the same network. I've tried to set this as:

```
'HOST': '192.168.1.34',
'PORT': '3306',
```

and

```
'HOST': '192.168.1.34',
'PORT': '',
```

but both caused this `OperationalError`:

```
(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.34'(10061)")
```

SOLUTION: credit @cdhowie

1. Config bind-address to the host you want in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
2. Create a new user for the host you want to give an access (if you don't have one).
3. Check privileges for that user (if access denied).

Comment: Have you checked the firewall on 192.168.1.34?  Is MySQL on 192.168.1.34 bound to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @cdhowie I have no idea how to check the firewall and bounding of MySQL. Please tell me how to do.

Comment: what OS is the MySQL server running on?

Comment: By default, Debian-based distros configure MySQL to bind to localhost only, which means that other hosts cannot connect to it.  Fix your MySQL configuration and it will work.

Comment: @cdhowie: This should probably be an answer

Comment: @Jim: Yeah, I've gone ahead and added one.

Comment: @Protocole: You should upvote and then "accept" cdhowie's answer, since it helped you solve the problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By default, Debian-based distros configure MySQL to bind to localhost only, which means that other hosts cannot connect to it. Fix your MySQL configuration and it will work.

Edit `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and change this line:

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

To this:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

This will expose MySQL to all network interfaces, so make sure that you have security measures in place if this server is exposed to untrusted hosts.

Comment: works fine !! thanks a lot, but as u mentioned, makes me think about security, as it is open to every ip

Comment: @Davo Of course you would also want to use a firewall to restrict access to the server. ;)