# Access remote MySQL server without editing my.conf

Tags: mysql, django

I want to connect my Django app (hosted on a VPS) to a database hosted on another server with more memory, so I can run stuff and add things to the database without the risk of it getting killed for using too much memory on my VPS. The things I've seen about this (e.g., [How to connect to MySQL server on another host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130239/how-to-connect-to-mysql-server-on-another-host)) all involve editing `my.cnf` and changing the `bind-address` line. I a)don't have root privileges to do this, and b)don't want to expose other users' MySQL dbs to potential security risks. I tried editing `~/.my.cnf` to change the `bind-address` thing, but that doesn't seem to work.

I also found http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-connect-to-your-database-remotely, which suggests creating `'user'@'remote-ip-address'` and then `grant`ing that user permissions. I tried that, but I keep getting `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '(the server's address)' (110)` when I try `mysql -u username -p -h (the server's address)`.

I have access to the `root` user for MySQL, but no other admin privileges on the server where I want to set up the database. Is there any way to configure things so Django can access this remote db without directly editing `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`?

Answer (score 1):

The `bind-address` doesn't specify which IPs can connect to that server, but which address is MySQL listening to. So, just set it to 0.0.0.0 and it will work. Please make sure you've got a user account with that address. Check `mysql.user` table.

Addressing the root-access thing:
* If you installed mysql manually, you've got root access.
* If you didn't install mysql manually, but it's a service provided by the VPS hosting, then the bind-address should be 0.0.0.0 (or at least not 127.0.0.1). If it's not the case, contact them because they're screwing up pretty bad.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT, CLARIFICATION:**

MySQL `bind-address` is not a security constraint. If you want to allow some addresses to connect to the server you should create/grant users with the that address specified, like this

```
CREATE USER 'bobdole'@'192.168.10.221';
```

Comment: I need to connect Django on my VPS to the database on the other server. As far as I can tell, changing the mysql settings on my VPS won't help anything, and I don't have root permissions to change the settings on the other server (I also don't want to compromise its security.)

Comment: I edited the answer to address your security concerns. Now, let me help you with your problem. What address do you have set right now? `cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf | grep bind`

Comment: Right, I did that: `CREATE USER 'user'@'(VPS IP address)'`, `GRANT ALL ON mydb.* to 'user'@'(VPS IP address)' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'`. But like I said above, I get `ERROR 2003 (HY000)` when I try to connect from my VPS to the other server.

Comment: `VPS IP address` is the address from the VPS with the Django installation, right? I'm wondering if it's using some sort of private IP to connect to VPSs. Can you check with your support?

Comment: Please, make sure the `bind-address` is `0.0.0.0`

Comment: I changed `bind-address` on my VPS to `0.0.0.0`. It doesn't seem to be helping. I don't have root permissions to edit `my.conf` on the other server, hence my question.

Answer (score 0):

Rather hacky, but I think this should be possible with [MySQL Proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-proxy.html) listening on an unprivileged port on the public IP, proxying all queries to the mysqld which is running locally.