# Connect to virtual machine's mysql database from host, windows 7, debian

Tags: mysql, linux, debian, vmware

I have win7 OS and VMware v10, and have Debian 6 installed in it. I want to connect to Debian's mysql database.

1) I have set in network connections of the VM option - Bridged.

2) In Debian I can connect to mysql, it works fine.

3) The Ip address of the guest is `192.168.0.103`.

When I try to connect from windows, using `mysql -h192.168.0.103 -uuser1 -p` and then type the password, it says

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.0.103' (10061)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, the problem was associated with mysql config in debian, here is the solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7140877/932473